# How can I parse JSON to test the string value of a nested key?

Tags: text-processing, grep, string, json

For example, here is my program's output (bspwm, if you wanted to know):

```
{
  "id": 29360131,
  "splitType": "vertical",
  "splitRatio": 0.5,
  "birthRotation": 90,
  "vacant": true,
  "sticky": false,
  "private": false,
  "locked": false,
  "presel": null,
  "rectangle": {
    "x": 0,
    "y": 0,
    "width": 1920,
    "height": 1200
  },
  "firstChild": null,
  "secondChild": null,
  "client": {
    "className": "Termite",
    "instanceName": "termite",
    "borderWidth": 1,
    "state": "floating",
    "lastState": "tiled",
    "layer": "normal",
    "lastLayer": "normal",
    "urgent": false,
    "visible": true,
    "icccmFocus": true,
    "icccmInput": true,
    "minWidth": 10,
    "maxWidth": 0,
    "minHeight": 19,
    "maxHeight": 0,
    "wmStatesCount": 0,
    "wmState": [],
    "tiledRectangle": {
      "x": 0,
      "y": 0,
      "width": 958,
      "height": 1198
    },
    "floatingRectangle": {
      "x": 638,
      "y": 394,
      "width": 642,
      "height": 410
    }
  }
}
```

I want to check if `"state"` is not `"tiling"`. In this case, it is `"floating"`.

Comment: If str is the long string you present, then: `echo "$str" | grep -oP '"state":"\K([^"]*)'`

Comment: `<your program> | grep -q '"state": *"tiling"'` || echo not tiling` Or use a json parser like `jq`.

Answer (score 3):

### Using jq with Boolean Tests

Given that your JSON is stored in a variable named *json*, you could do the following at the shell prompt:

```
$ echo "$json" | jq '.client.state | test("tiling")'
false
```

This correctly returns false because your corpus contains the value `floating` instead.

### Negating Tests

Alternatively, if you wanted to test that the value is *not* `tiling`, you can use the `| not` filter to negate the logic of your test. For example:

```
$ echo "$json" | jq '.client.state | test("tiling") | not'
true
```

This correctly returns true because the client state isn't `tiling`, it's `floating`.

### Extracting the Value

In case you want to make sure your filters are working in a sane way, you can also use jq to parse out the value for that nested key. For example:

```
$ echo "$json" | jq .client.state
"floating"
```

You can then use that information to validate your tests and filters, or simply pass it along a shell pipeline to `fgrep` or `fgrep -v` if you don't mind spawning an additional process.

Answer (score 1):

Better option is to use a JSON parser.

If you insist on using `grep`:

Assuming your `grep` supports PCRE (`-P`):

```
bspwm | grep -Po '"state":\K[^,]*'
```

This will get the value (with quotes) of the key `"state"`.

If you don't want surrounding quotes around the key:

```
bspwm | grep -Po '"state":"\K[^"]*'
```

For example:

```
% grep -Po '"state":\K[^,]*' <<<'{"id":29360131,"splitType":"vertical","splitRatio":0.500000,"birthRotation":90,"vacant":true,"sticky":false,"private":false,"locked":false,"presel":null,"rectangle":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":1920,"height":1200},"firstChild":null,"secondChild":null,"client":{"className":"Termite","instanceName":"termite","borderWidth":1,"state":"floating","lastState":"tiled","layer":"normal","lastLayer":"normal","urgent":false,"visible":true,"icccmFocus":true,"icccmInput":true,"minWidth":10,"maxWidth":0,"minHeight":19,"maxHeight":0,"wmStatesCount":0,"wmState":[],"tiledRectangle":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":958,"height":1198},"floatingRectangle":{"x":638,"y":394,"width":642,"height":410}}'

"floating"


% grep -Po '"state":"\K[^"]*' <<<'{"id":29360131,"splitType":"vertical","splitRatio":0.500000,"birthRotation":90,"vacant":true,"sticky":false,"private":false,"locked":false,"presel":null,"rectangle":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":1920,"height":1200},"firstChild":null,"secondChild":null,"client":{"className":"Termite","instanceName":"termite","borderWidth":1,"state":"floating","lastState":"tiled","layer":"normal","lastLayer":"normal","urgent":false,"visible":true,"icccmFocus":true,"icccmInput":true,"minWidth":10,"maxWidth":0,"minHeight":19,"maxHeight":0,"wmStatesCount":0,"wmState":[],"tiledRectangle":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":958,"height":1198},"floatingRectangle":{"x":638,"y":394,"width":642,"height":410}}'

floating
```

Comment: Why don't grep directly, like `grep -q '"state": *"tiling"'`?

Answer (score 1):

Using a dedicated JSON parser, like [Jshon](http://kmkeen.com/jshon/), is a more robust approach:

```
jshon -e client -e state -u < file             
floating
```

Answer (score 0):

another easy alternative to extract info from JSON and test it is [`jtc`](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc) tool (assuming source json is in `file.json`):

```
bash $ cat file.json | jtc -w "[state]:<tiling>" | grep "tiling" >/dev/null; if [ $? == 0 ]; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi;
false
bash $ 
bash $ cat file.json | jtc -w "[state]:<floating>" | grep "floating" >/dev/null; if [ $? == 0 ]; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi;
true
bash $
```